# Regex, match the most informative pattern

Tags: c#, regex, natural-language-processing

I have a function that is designed to parse an utterance (or typed in string) and identify the intent as a yes or no answer.

There are many ways of saying "yes" to something, and similarly for "no" or "unsure"; however, some of these phrases may include sub-phrases that have alternative meanings. For example: `certainly` vs. `certainly not`.

I can't guarantee that `not` will always refer to a negative statement either, for example `sure` vs `not sure`; `I do not know`; or even `why not!` (the latter could be taken as an affirmative.)

Since I am interested only in phrases and sub-phrases (not words within words), I realised that the way to identify the most informative phrase is to attempt to match them in order of size. Also, if the larger phrase matches, I also don't want to match the sub-phrases as separate. Fortunately, there is a feature of regular expressions that can do this quite easily.

`/\b(a b c|a b|a c|b c|a|b|c)\b/` where 'a', 'b', and 'c' are words, will match the first phrase it can find over the others. Therefore, `/\b(a b c|a b|a c|b c|a|b|c)\b/.matches("a b c a") == ["a b c", "a"]` as opposed to `["a", "b c", "a"]` or another combination.
[Example here](http://www.regextester.com/?fam=96494)

(Note that for this to work, the order of the 'or'ed phases need to be in descending order of length. Regex captures lazy, and will succeed on the first 'or'-block in the capture group.)

So here's a test function of the idea in C#:

```
public enum Affirmation { No=0, Yes, Unsure, NoAnswer }
public Affirmation getAffirmation(string utterance)
{
    string[] yesses = new string[] { "yes", "yep", "y", "yeah", "certainly", "sure", "why not", "agree", "affirmative" };
    string[] nos = new string[] { "no", "nope", "nah", "nup", "negative", "n", "certainly not", "yeah nah" };
    string[] unsures = new string[] { "unsure", "not sure", "i don't know", "maybe", "come again", "i do not know" };
    string[] responses = yesses.Concat(nos).Concat(unsures).OrderByDescending(w => w.Length).ToArray();
    Regex response = new Regex($"\\b({string.Join("|", responses)})\\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    MatchCollection matches = response.Matches(utterance);
    if (matches.Count == 0)
    {
        return Affirmation.NoAnswer;
    }

    IEnumerable<Affirmation> affirmations = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(m => {
        if (yesses.Contains(m.Value.ToLower())) { return Affirmation.Yes; }
        else if (nos.Contains(m.Value.ToLower())) { return Affirmation.No; }
        else { return Affirmation.Unsure; }
    });
    return affirmations.Aggregate((agg, aff) =>
    {
        if (agg == Affirmation.Unsure || agg == aff) { return agg; }
        else { return Affirmation.Unsure; }
    });
}
```

Obviously the three string arrays aren't particularly long in this example; however there's no reason I couldn't try and enumerate all sorts of different phrases and categorise them by intent.

My question is with that Regex builder:

```
Regex response = new Regex($"\\b({string.Join("|", responses)})\\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

This pattern could end up being very large.

- Is there a limit to the number of characters for a Regex string?
- Is there a performance issue to worry about as a capture block
  becomes an extremely large 'Or' block?
- Is there a better way to do this in general?

Answer (score 2):

I cannot say much about the limits of the pattern, the only one that I encountered so far was the length of the group name.

---

> ```
> IEnumerable<Affirmation> affirmations = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(m => {
>     if (yesses.Contains(m.Value.ToLower())) { return Affirmation.Yes; }
>     else if (nos.Contains(m.Value.ToLower())) { return Affirmation.No; }
>     else { return Affirmation.Unsure; }
> });
> ```

You can however make the lookup faster by using a `HashSet<T>`. Its `Contains` method is an *O(1)* operation unlike the array's *O(n)*.

Additionaly you should instantiate it with `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` so that you don't have to use `ToLower/ToUpper`.

---

Another possibility would be to use named groups and catch the expressions there so that you can just use them without looking them up in the collections.